# How to import a simple class in working directory with python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I read various answer ([relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)), but none work to import a simple class. I have this structure:

```
__init__.py   (empty)
my_script.py
other_script.py
my_class.py
```

I want to use **my_class.py** in both script (**my_script.py** and **other_script.py**). Like all answer suggest, I just use:

```
from .my_class import My_class
```

but I always get

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I am using **Python 3.5** and **PyCharm 2016.1.2**. Does I need to configure the `__init__.py`? How can I import a simple class?

**Edit**

All the files are in the working directory. I just use the Pycharm to run and I wasn't having problem until try to import the class.

Comment: Please do not name your file `class.py` as `class` has a meaning in Python.

Comment: lol, this was just to make it easy to understand in question. But good point

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your current working directory is ***not*** the one that contains these files.   For example, if the path to `__init__.py` is `spam/eggs/__init__.py`, make sure you are working in directory `spam`—or alternatively, that `/path/to/spam` is in `sys.path` and you are working in some third place. Either way, do not attempt to work in directory `eggs`.   To test your code, you say `import eggs`.

The reasoning is as follows.  Since you're using `__init__.py` you clearly want to treat this collection of files as a [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages). To work as a package, a directory must fulfill both the following criteria:

1. it contains a file called `__init__.py`
2. its ***parent*** directory is part of the search path (or the parent directory is your current working directory); in effect, a package directory must masquerade as a file, i.e. be findable in exactly the same way that a single-file module might be found.

If you're working *inside* the package directory you may not be fulfilling criterion 2.   You can do a straightforward `import my_class` from there, certainly, but the "relative import" thing you're trying is a feature that only a fully-working package will support.

Comment: Soo... The problem is the working directory. I CAN'T import the class in the working directory? And yes, all the files are in the working directory!

Comment: You can `import my_class` on its own from there, for sure, but if you want to wrap multiple files up in a package,  stay out of the package directory itself.  (see edit)